# Grant read/read-write access to SSAS cubes

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a requirement to grant read access on SSAS cubes to one windows group and read/write access to another group. I have multiple SSAS cubes on my server.

The question is:

1. What minimum rights should I grant to the user?
2. Is there a way to apply this rights on multiple cubes. As manually creating roles on each SSAS cubes is painful. I have lot of SSAS cubes. So looking for an easy way to do this.

Comment: Can someone please help me?

Comment: Sorry nobody replied. Are you still looking for help? Clarify what you mean by read-write? Do you mean users that can perform writeback from Excel to save some values to the cube? Or do you mean users who can kickoff processing (reloading) the cube?

Comment: No, I needed users to only write the cubes. Since I didn't find much on the internet, I moved forward and granted access manually on all the cubes and the required servers.

Answer (score 1):

Writeback permissions are a bit tricky. I documented them [here](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2012/1/10/excel-writeback-security-and-leveraging-the-updateable-cell-property). The relevant part is:

> Next, build a separate Writeback role. On the Cubes tab, grant
>   Read/Write, check Process, and (optionally) Drillthrough permissions.
>   I’m frankly not sure why you need Process permissions to perform ROLAP
>   writeback, but it appears you need Process permissions for ROLAP or
>   MOLAP writeback.
>
> In the Data Sources tab, make sure to grant Read permissions on the
>   data source used for writeback. For example, when I created my
>   writeback partition, I used the Greg Test data source to direct that
>   writeback table to live in another database (such as a database with
>   Full recovery model).

Sounds like you already figured it out but we can document this for posterity.